Handle high response time Open Feign Rest Client
I am building a springboot application with a spring open feign client with a readout time as 60 minutes as response time is around 50 minutes. I was able to configure the read time out but response is never received. I can see that backend shows HTTP/1.1" 200 OK.
My worry is if there is some underlying timeout may be socket is closed. But I am not sure how to get a grip on that. Can someone help me understand how to handle high response time with Feign Rest client. (spring-cloud-starter-openfeign)
